# MAMP PRO - "Network Error (dns_server_failure)" when setting up VHosts

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, mamp, operating-system

I'm trying to set up a virtual host locally on MAMP PRO; I've done this before on other machines and it worked like a charm. This time, however, when I try to point my browser to the path defined in MAMP PRO, I get a "dns_server_failure". I feel like I've tried everything, but I still can't get it to work. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Address of your DNS resolver doesn't know about your newly created virtual hosts. You need to set proper DNS records or use DynamicDNS if it's appropriate. You can find more info here:
http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/server/dynamic-dns